# Comparing date in subquery prevents SQL Server from using index

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm trying to filter only events that happened within 30 days after the company was created (`RegisteredUtc`).

Does anyone know how to rewrite this query to make sure that predicate uses the index that exists?

I've tried both with an index that has (eventtype, timeutc) and includes (companyid) and one that has (eventtype) and includes (companyid, timeutc).

This is the query that does what I want. **NOTE**: between these 3 queries it's only the last predicate in the first where clause that changes.

```
select 
     DATEPART(year, q.RegisteredUtc) as [year], 
     DATEPART(month, q.RegisteredUtc) as [month],
     Count(*) as [Count]
from 
    (select 
        c.Id,
        c.RegisteredUtc,
        (select count(*) 
         from dbo.events sc
         where sc.companyId = c.Id 
           and sc.eventtype = 'CreateInvoice' 
           and sc.TimeUtc < DATEADD(day, 30, c.RegisteredUtc)) as [Count]
    from 
        dbo.companies c) as q
where 
    q.Count > 0
group by 
    DATEPART(year, q.RegisteredUtc), DATEPART(month, q.RegisteredUtc)
```

But it's very slow because of the and `TimeUtc < DATEADD(day, 30, c.RegisteredUtc)`. Without that it uses the indexes and runs very fast but with that predicate there it does a Eager spool that is very expensive instead of using the index.

There are actually indexes available. Confirmed by simply swapping `DATEADD(day, 30, c.RegisteredUtc)`with a constant which made the query fast again.

This is also slow.

```
select 
     DATEPART(year, q.RegisteredUtc) as [year], 
     DATEPART(month, q.RegisteredUtc) as [month],
     Count(*) as [Count]
from 
    (select 
        c.Id,
        c.RegisteredUtc,
        (select count(*) 
         from dbo.events sc
         where sc.companyId = c.Id 
           and sc.eventtype = 'CreateInvoice' 
           and sc.TimeUtc < c.RegisteredUtc) as [Count]
    from 
        dbo.companies c) as q
where 
    q.Count > 0
group by 
    DATEPART(year, q.RegisteredUtc), DATEPART(month, q.RegisteredUtc)
```

This query hits the index and works fast though but of course doesn't produce the correct results.

```
select 
     DATEPART(year, q.RegisteredUtc) as [year], 
     DATEPART(month, q.RegisteredUtc) as [month],
     Count(*) as [Count]
from 
    (select 
        c.Id,
        c.RegisteredUtc,
        (select count(*) 
         from dbo.events sc
         where sc.companyId = c.Id 
           and sc.eventtype = 'CreateInvoice' 
           and sc.TimeUtc = c.RegisteredUtc) as [Count]
    from 
        dbo.companies c) as q
where 
    q.Count > 0
group by 
    DATEPART(year, q.RegisteredUtc), DATEPART(month, q.RegisteredUtc)
```

Comment: Please always label the columns to the table

Comment: Column types, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it you are not even using the inner count
If it matches the join then the count > 0

```
select DATEPART(year,  q.RegisteredUtc) as [year], 
       DATEPART(month, q.RegisteredUtc) as [month],
       Count(*) as [Count]
  from ( select distinct c.Id, c.RegisteredUtc 
           from dbo.companies c
           join dbo.events sc
             on sc.companyId = c.Id 
            and eventtype = 'CreateInvoice' 
            and TimeUtc < DATEADD(day, 30, c.RegisteredUtc)             
       ) as q
group by DATEPART(year, q.RegisteredUtc), DATEPART(month, q.RegisteredUtc)
```

`where exists` may work better. Your query is confusing to me.  You get a count just to compare it to > 0 and you are worried about not using an in index?

Comment: I have removed the paramters here. > 0 is normally > @limit where the application defines that. 

That count doesn't slow much down. It runs in less then a second normally and takes about 70s as soon as the index on TimeUtc is not used.

Comment: Thank you! 

You solution certainly ran fast. Just going to compare the results too.

Comment: This answer works out nicely for this use case here so I will mark it as the answer. 

A friend found out that changing the index solved it too. I though I had verified that by running against a fixed date but apparently my understanding of indexes need a brush up.

Comment: @MikaelEliasson In general don't do stuff that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile to compute the DATEADD(day, 30, c.RegisteredUtc) in the select and then compare TimeUtc with the computed column, in other words:

```
select 
c.Id,
c.RegisteredUtc,
DATEADD(day, 30, c.RegisteredUtc) as RegisteredUtc30
(
select count(*)
from dbo.events sc
where sc.companyId = c.Id
and sc.eventtype = 'CreateInvoice'
and sc.TimeUtc < RegisteredUtc30
from dbo.companies c
```